# Is it mandatory to pass parameter in catch block in c++?

Tags: c++, try-catch

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i=5;
    cout<<"here1";
    try
    {    if(i==5)
          throw ;
          cout<<"here2";
    }
    catch()
    {
      cout<<"here3"; 
    }

     cout<<"here4";
    return 0;
}
```

error: expected type-specifier before ')' token
  catch()
        ^

Comment: How will compiler know what you want to catch then? If you want to catch all exception types use `...`.

Comment: Invoking `throw` without an exception causes it to rethrow the one currently being handled. Since there doesn't seem to be an existing exception by the time your code reaches `throw;` the runtime will invoke `terminate` and your exception handler (`catch`) will never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

You should write it as:

```
catch(...)
```

In case you want to catch an exception regardless of what type it has.

Comment: This isn't very clear. What arguments are you referring to? The ones passed to the exception or are you referring to the exception itself as an argument passed to `catch(...)`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Yes. I'm referring to catching any kind of exception regardless of its type. I'm making it clearer

Answer (score 1):

> ## Is it mandatory to pass parameter in catch block in c++?

Yes, it is.

`catch()` always needs a parameter or at least an ellipsis (which matches any unknown exception type). From the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch)

> ```
> catch ( attr(optional) type-specifier-seq declarator ) 
>       compound-statement    (1) 
> catch ( attr(optional) type-specifier-seq abstract-declarator(optional) ) 
>       compound-statement    (2) 
> catch ( ... ) compound-statement  (3)
> ```

This corresponds to the fact that `throw` statements always need a type (to throw). A plain `throw;` statement inside a catch block re-throws the current exception caught.

---

That said, the `throw;` statement (out of context from a `catch` block) and the `catch()` signature from your example are invalid as the compiler reported.

Comment: Actually, `throw;` is valid

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In companion with a concrete exception type formerly thrown, yes (or not)?

Comment: Yes. It rethrows.

Comment: @Lightness Needed some more explanation I see (C++ standard reference would be even better may be).

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ellipsis to specify any exception, also this does not apply to read access violations, or write access violations, and use it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i=5;
    cout<<"here1";
    try
    {    if(i==5)
          throw ;
          cout<<"here2";
    }
    catch(...) //'...' means anything, here any exception
    {
      cout<<"here3"; 
    }

     cout<<"here4";
    return 0;
}
```

I also recommend using the generic `std::exception` class like this:

```
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch-all handler, which is activated for any exception

```
try { 
    /* */ 
} 
catch (...) { 
    /* */ 
}
```